# stack multiple csv files each with headers from windows 10 cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple csv files with the same columns, each with headers, each with hundreds of thousands of rows, how can I stack/append/rowbind them on top of each other, keeping only the first file's header?

This question is different from the one marked as a duplicate as the other question does not ask for any appending, only to remove headers.

Comment: `(type "file1.csv" & more +1 "file2.csv" & more "file3.csv") > "combinedfile.csv"` -- but this works only if both `file2.csv` and `file3.csv` do not contain more than 65534 lines; and the line lengths are limited to 8190 characters, I think...

Comment: @aschipfl, pretty sure there is no line length limitation with `MORE` and `TYPE`.  But you are correct about the number of lines.

Comment: @aschipfl Have updated question.

Comment: We just discussed this topic over on [dostips.com](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7723).

Comment: @Squashman, I was not sure about `more`'s maximum line length; I just tested it and it amounts to 65535 characters; after each 65535 characters, a line-break is inserted...

Comment: If the header contains something that cannot appear within the data rows, the following might work: `(type "file1.csv" & findstr /V /B /C:"ID," "file2.csv" & findstr /V /B /C:"ID," "file3.csv") > "combinedfile.csv"`, supposing the header begins with `ID,` and no other line can begin with that...